# Lower bound for Convex hull

Tags: complexity-theory, computational-geometry, lower-bounds

By making use of the fact that sorting $n$ numbers requires 
$\Omega(n \log n)$ steps for any optimal algorithm (which uses 'comparison' for sorting), how can I prove that finding the [convex-hull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull) of $n$ points is bounded by $\Omega (n \log n)$ steps?

Comment: For your question see, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms#Lower_bound_on_computational_complexity . A somehow surprising fact is that even if you  choose some other model (like the quadratic decision model) the complexity is still bounded by $O(n\log{n})$

Answer (score 6):

If you could create the convex-hull in $o(n \log n)$ time, this would imply, that you can sort $n$ numbers in $o(n\log n)$ time.

You do this with contradiction. You have $n$ numbers $(x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_n)$, which you would like to sort. From these numbers, you create points $P$ in 2D space in some fashion. For example $p_i=(x_i,x_i^2)$.

On these newly constructed points $P$ you call the algorithm for convex hull, which returns you the actual convex hull.

After that, you simultaneously traverse upper and lower hull, from the lower left-most point in (which you find in $O(n)$ time), to the upper right-most point. With this traversal you actually sort the numbers. Let $p_i$ and $p_j$ be the next points on lower and upper hull, then if $x_i<x_j$, you move one step ahead on the lower hull and add $x_i$ to the end of the sorted array (else you take one step ahead on the upper hull and add $x_j$ to the array). You then finish when the traversals meet in the upper right-most point of the convex hull.

The algorithm that I described is run in $O(n)$ time. So if the convex-hull algorithm would be $o(n\log n)$, the sorting of $n$ numbers could be also done in $o(n\log n)$ time, which is a contradiction since we know that sorting $n$ numbers takes at least $\Omega(n \log n)$ time.

Comment: I am not sure choosing points in this way is safe. Putting them on a parabola $p_i = (x_i,x_i^2)$ seems safer.

Comment: Yes, I suppose you are right that this is safer.

Comment: Odd... a problem with text formatting on stackoverflow. Everything was there, I just clicked edit and then save, and everything is here. :/

Comment: I think, It's better to explicitly mention $f(x)=x^2$ (the way you choose for points) causes to convex polygon.

Comment: I straightened out your Landau symbols -- [take care](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/57)! Also, "The algorithm that I described is run in $O(n)$ time." is wrong; $o(n\log n) \neq O(n)$. The greater idea seems to work, though -- *if* you explain why the $\Omega(n\log n)$ bound applies to this setting. As far as I can see, the algorithm you construct is not (necessarily) a comparison sort.

Comment: It seems to me that this reduction shows that producing a representation of a convex hull as a list of points or lines *in the order that they appear in the cycle* is $\Omega(n \log n)$, but it's not clear to me that the convex hull problem asks for this much.  Is it possible that some convex hull algorithm could produce the *set* of points in the hull, but in unspecified order, in $o(n \log n)$?  (Similar to how you can find the smallest $k$ of $n$ numbers in $O(n)$ if you don't care about their order.)  Or can the reduction be modified to fix this?

Comment: @j_random_hacker http://infolab.stanford.edu/pub/cstr/reports/cs/tr/79/733/CS-TR-79-733.pdf